# Bitbucket Branch Source plugin not setting TAG_NAME variable when checking out tags

Tags: git, jenkins, tags, bitbucket

Running a multibranch pipeline to build all branches/tags on push from bitbucket server.  Everything is working except it appears to be checking out tags as branches, and thus the TAG_NAME variable is never set.  I don't have admin privs on the jenkins server and cannot control configuration, nor even view it.

I have requested that: https://plugins.jenkins.io/basic-branch-build-strategies/ get added, but I have no idea if they will or will not add it.

I was attempting to use:

```
stage("Publish") {
   when {
        buildingTag()
        
   }
   steps {
          do some stuff
   }
```

to only publish when the checkout is a tag, but the check always fails.

I've verified the hash checked out is the tag's hash.

I'm not sure what else to look for as I'm not super familiar with Jenkins.

note:  the tags are annotated tags.